# Display 4 pages of a sub-report in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to display only 4 pages on my Crystal report, however, I am getting an extra empty page. I cannot pin the reason to what sounds like a trivial issue.

My report has the following:
- No fields in the main report - This is not avoidable.
- One sub-report. 
- In order to have the sub-report header repeat I followed this [method described here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tip-how-to-add-a-page-header-to-a-sub-report-in-crystal-rep/). (I just do not understand what the formula means and whether this is the reason for the extra page but I am getting a header as I require).
I am suppressing the pages in both the report and sub-report as follows: in the suppress I am using

```
if pagenumber>4 then true;
```

I tried to put in all my sections

```
Not(onLastRecord)
```

I am simply lost. All I need to do is print 4 pages only regardless how long the report/sub-report is. I also need the sub-report to have a repeating header. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the size:

-If possible supress group and report footers

-Right Click on each section you can and select "Fit Section"

-Change the color of some sections so you can see if any responsible for the extra page

-Maybe the paper is set to letter ? : Go Design - Page Setup, set A4 or you can also try no printer to see if something changes **( this last one will change the format of your fields so backup before)**

Comment: Thanks. still no success. I have the following notes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any footer sections that are not being used, try suppressing them.  This will remove empty white space that is added at the end of the report.  Another option is to adjust the size of your top and bottom margins, providing there are no design conflicts in doing so.

If you have any white space at the bottom of the sections that appear at the end of the report you could also reduce the height of that section to remove the white space.